# Using named pipes and fork in C / Linux

Tags: c, linux, fork, named-pipes

I'm trying to write simple console application that reads text from user, then changes lowercase to uppercase and finally prints result in console. 
It is working fine when I use only one pipe (e.g. without reading text from console), but works totally unpredictable when I use two.

Shouldn't '[Write]' wait for '[To upper]' until it send text?

I got following output:

> [Write] Waiting for txt to diplay.
>   [To upper] Waiting for txt to change.
>   [Write] Received following txt: 
>   [To upper] Received txt ().
>   [To upper] Changed txt send to [Write] ().
>   [Scan] Type your txt: 
>   [Scan] Txt received. Sending to [To upper] (y)

My code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#define SIZE 16
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    int f1,f2;
    char x[SIZE]={0};
    if( fork() )    
    {
        if( fork() )//[Write]
        {
            f1=open("upper-write",O_RDONLY);
            puts( "[Write] Waiting for txt to diplay." );
            read( f1, &x, sizeof( x ) );
            printf( "[Write] Received following txt: %s\n", x );
            close( f1 );
        }
        else//[Scan]
        {
            puts( "[Scan] Type your txt: " );
            //scanf ("%15s",x);//scanf not working now, so I change my char array by myself     
            x[0]='y';
            f2=open("scan-upper",O_WRONLY);
            printf( "[Scan] Txt received. Sending to [To upper] (%s)\n", x );
            write( f2, &x, sizeof( x ) );
            close( f2 );
        }
    } 
    else//[To upper]
    {
        puts( "[To upper] Waiting for txt to change." );
        f2=open("scan-upper",O_RDONLY);
        read( f2, &x, sizeof( x ) );
        close( f2 );

        printf( "[To upper] Received txt (%s).\n" ,x);  
        for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
            if(x[i]>=97 && x[i] <=122)//lowercase -> uppercase
                x[i]-=32;


        f1=open("upper-write",O_WRONLY);
        write( f1, &x, sizeof( x ) );
        printf( "[To upper] Changed txt send to [Write] (%s).\n" ,x);
        close( f1 );
    }
}
```

Comment: You have no synchronization between calls. You have limited synchronization based on the nature of pipes -- can't read until the other end has written, but once the read is completed, the order of your printf's is not synchronized.

Comment: Could it be that your pipe is not empty initially? Then you have some non-printable byte read. And don't use your `SIZE` as a string length, since it isn't.

Comment: Any reason you need a named pipe instead of just using the [pipe system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pipe.html)?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to understand a couple of things to understand the problem.  First, after a `fork()` there's no guarantee as to which process gets to run first.  Second, `read()` returns immediately with a value of zero if the other end of the pipe isn't open for writing.

You're counting on the processes running in a certain order so that the pipes are all open on both sides before any reads take place.  Since that doesn't always happen, `read()` isn't always blocking.

You can solve this by opening both ends of all of your pipes before you `fork()`.  All of the processes will have file descriptors to both ends of the pipes.  Just call `close()` on the file descriptors you don't need in the corresponding processes.

Comment: My C is a bit rusty, but this sounds right.  Like the [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) says, "When attempting to read from an empty pipe or FIFO:... If no process has the pipe open for writing, read() shall return 0 to indicate end-of-file."

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure this isn't because your non-scan processes don't close stdin? You might want to do something like "close(0)" after the fork.

Alternatively, there's popen(), which might be interesting for this kind of stuff.

Comment: maybe the phrasing could've been better, but I actually do believe it's the answer :-)

Comment: If you do believe that, I rescind my comment :) But I don't think its a valid answer because of the OP's processes, only one is attempting to read from stdin (well, under his current code, none of them are). Closing the paths you don't need is nice but if you're not using them, you won't harm the other processes.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.